# Apache wicket 6.29x, RadioGroup with ListView with AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior ()

Tags: java, html, wicket, radio-group, wicket-6

I have a list and each item in this list I have a radioGroup for two options, depending on the choice a field appears for upload, I did very dynamic with dynamic id but the only iteration of AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior that works and the last radioGroup of the listView.

```
    LoadableDetachableModel<List<RegistroPresencaColaborador>> registroPresencasColab = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<RegistroPresencaColaborador>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        protected List<RegistroPresencaColaborador> load() {
            List<RegistroPresencaColaborador> list = new ArrayList<RegistroPresencaColaborador>();
            count=0;
            if(listaRegistroPresencas!=null && listaRegistroPresencas.size() > 0 ){
                list.addAll(listaRegistroPresencas);
            }
            return list;
        }
    };

    listViewRegistroColab = new ListView<RegistroPresencaColaborador>("listaRegistroPresencaColab",registroPresencasColab){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<RegistroPresencaColaborador> item) {
            final RegistroPresencaColaborador registroPreColaborador = item.getModelObject();




            count++;
            registroPreColaborador.setCount(count.toString());
            if(clicouSelecionarTodos !=null && getClicouSelecionarTodos()){
                registroPreColaborador.setFrequencia(RegistroPresencaColaborador.PRESENCA);
            }else if(clicouSelecionarTodos !=null && !getClicouSelecionarTodos()){
                registroPreColaborador.setFrequencia(RegistroPresencaColaborador.FALTA);
            }

            item.addOrReplace(new Label("colaborador",registroPreColaborador.getColaborador().getNome()).setOutputMarkupId(true));
---RadioGroup   item.addOrReplace(criarCampoFrequencia(registroPreColaborador));
            item.addOrReplace(criarDivAnexoColab(registroPreColaborador));


//item.add(criarDivLinkDownload(registroPreColaborador));
        }
    };
```

//Component RadioGroup

```
    private RadioGroup<Integer> criarCampoFrequencia(final RegistroPresencaColaborador registroPreColaborador ) {
    radioGroupTipo = new RadioGroup<Integer>("frequencia", new PropertyModel<Integer>(registroPreColaborador, "frequencia")){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            if(getAbstractBean().getId()!=null && getAbstractBean().getVisualizar()){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
    if(radioGroupSelecionouTodos.getModelObject() != null && !radioGroupSelecionouTodos.getModelObject() || registroPreColaborador.getId() != null && registroPreColaborador.getFrequencia().equals(RegistroPresencaColaborador.FALTA) ){
        radioGroupTipo.add(new AttributeModifier("class", "switch-toggle switch-candy switch-candy-red large-4"));
    }
    radioGroupTipo.setRequired(true);
    radioGroupTipo.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    radioGroupTipo.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    radioGroupTipo.setRenderBodyOnly(false);

    radioGroupTipo.add(new Radio<Integer>("tipoPresenca", new Model<Integer>(RegistroPresencaColaborador.PRESENCA)).add(new AttributeModifier("id", "tipoPresenca"+registroPreColaborador.getCount())).setOutputMarkupId(true));
    radioGroupTipo.add(new Radio<Integer>("tipoFalta", new Model<Integer>(RegistroPresencaColaborador.FALTA)).add(new AttributeModifier("id", "tipoFalta"+registroPreColaborador.getCount())).setOutputMarkupId(true));
    radioGroupTipo.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if(radioGroupTipo.getModelObject() != null && radioGroupTipo.getModelObject().equals(RegistroPresencaColaborador.FALTA)){
                radioGroupTipo.add(new AttributeModifier("class", "switch-toggle switch-candy switch-candy-red large-4"));
            }else if(radioGroupTipo.getModelObject() != null &&  radioGroupTipo.getModelObject().equals(RegistroPresencaColaborador.PRESENCA)){

                radioGroupTipo.add(new AttributeModifier("class", "switch-toggle switch-candy switch-candy-green large-4"));
            }
            target.add(radioGroupTipo);
            target.add(divAtualizaArquivo);
        }
    });

    radioGroupTipo.add(criarLabelPresenca(registroPreColaborador));
    radioGroupTipo.add(criarLabelFalta(registroPreColaborador));
    return radioGroupTipo;
}
```

//label for each radioGroup

```
private Label criarLabelFalta(final RegistroPresencaColaborador registroPreColaborador ){
    Label falta = new Label("falta", "Falta");
    falta.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    falta.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    falta.add(new AttributeModifier("for", "tipoFalta"+registroPreColaborador.getCount()));
    return falta;
}

private Label criarLabelPresenca(final RegistroPresencaColaborador registroPreColaborador ){
    Label presenca = new Label("presenca", "Presença");
    presenca.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    presenca.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    presenca.add(new AttributeModifier("for", "tipoPresenca"+registroPreColaborador.getCount()));
    return presenca;
}
```

//my HTML cod

```
    <tr wicket:id="listaRegistroPresencaColab">
                                                                            <td style="text-align: left;"><span wicket:id="colaborador">Colaborador</span></td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 20%; border: 1px solid #333;   border-radius: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">
                                                            <div wicket:id="frequencia"  class="switch-toggle switch-candy large-6 ">
                                                                                        <input wicket:id="tipoPresenca" type="radio" /><label onclick="" wicket:id="presenca"  >Presença</label>
                                                                                        <input wicket:id="tipoFalta"   type="radio"/><label onclick="" wicket:id="falta" >Falta</label>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="text-align: left;"><div wicket:id="divAtualizaArquivo">  <input wicket:id="arquivoAnexoRegistro" type="file" class="form-control"/> </div></td>
                                                                        </tr>
```

//IMAGEM
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/opera_instantaneo_2019-01-14_114545_localhost-png

Has anyone else been through this or do you know a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCION

declare locally, if you need to give target use a WebMarkupContainer before and target it.

```
private RadioGroup<Integer> criarCampoFrequencia( RegistroPresencaColaborador registroPreColaborador ) {
    final RadioGroup<Integer> radioGroupTipo = new RadioGroup<Integer>("frequencia", new PropertyModel<Integer>(registroPreColaborador, "frequencia")){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            if(getAbstractBean().getId()!=null && getAbstractBean().getVisualizar()){
                return false;

            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Ajax updates work for your last iteration only, strongly suggests that you have duplicate ids in your markup.

Note that you don't need to fiddle with `setOutputMarkupId()` or `new AttributeModifier("id")`, since `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` will automatically generate the necessary markup id.

I didn't spot any error in your code though, so please re-check your resulting markup in the browser.

For `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` the markup id on your "frequencia" div is crucial, the ones from the radio inputs are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, well I looked in the browser and the id's differ, if I put new AttributeModifier ("id" ..) because in the label I use the new AttributeModifier ("for", ..) with msm value. https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/ids-png-280d8017-b75c-4637-a6e0-eede05a5b056

Comment: well sincerity I do not know if the error is my or the of wicket 6.X.

Comment: Sorry, missed the fact that you're using those ids for the labels. Your markup looks fine, I'm afraid you'll have to create a quickstart to identify the problem.

Comment: How would this "quick start", well, I've been in the company with this error since yesterday and I think I've tried everything I know

Comment: Build a https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html , try to replicate the problem as small as possible and preferrably find your own error while doing so :P

Comment: living and learning, I was declaring RadioGroup as a global variable because I was targeting it in another JaxEvent, so that's the last iteration of the list that worked.